# Visual studio change color of temp variable in Lambda

Tags: c#, visual-studio, colors, themes

With my current color scheme, the temp variables in C# Lambda expressions are difficult to look at.  If possible, I need to change the color.

In this example, I need to target the color of `x`:

```
var name = names.Where(x => x == "John");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Visual Studio menu `Tools` > `Options`, then expand `Environment` / `Fonts and Colors`. In the list go to `User Members - xy` or `User Types - xy` to change all the colors. You are looking for `User Members - Parameters`.

See [image and doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/how-to-change-fonts-and-colors-in-the-editor?view=vs-2019).

Comment: User Members - Parameters did it.  Thanks!